# My ASM Program for x86 8086 dont print well

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I have this code in asm x86 with DOSBox virtualization :

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
.code
main proc
  mov ah,1
  int 21h
  mov bl,al
  mov al,1
  int 21h
  add bl,al
  sub bl,'0'
  mov dl,bl
  mov ah,2
  int 21h
  mov ah,4ch
  int 21h
main endp
end main
```

[My expected output was a number and i get this ascii character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5luT8.png)

The program supposes to add a number from terminal and print in the console. I expect that my code was wrong and not my environment.

Thank you for the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mov al,1     <-- function number goes in AH
int 21h
add bl,al
```

When you ask for the second character you made the error of storing the function number in `AL` where it should have been `AH`. Although the DOS api does not mention that `AH` would change with this function, you can not trust this to be true.

```
mov ah, 1
int 21h
mov bl, al

mov ah, 1
int 21h
add bl, al     ; This now contains 2 times '0'

sub bl, '0'    ; Here you correctly subtract 1 of those
mov dl, bl
mov ah, 2
int 21h
```

The way you worked with that single `sub bl, '0'` is fine and a bit shorter, but most people would solve it like this:

```
mov ah, 01h
int 21h          ; eg. input '3'
sub al, '0'      ; '3' - '0' = 3
mov bl, al       ; 3

mov ah, 01h
int 21h          ; eg. input '5'
sub al, '0'      ; '5' - '0' = 5
add bl, al       ; 3 + 5 = 8

mov dl, bl
add dl, '0'      ; 8 + '0' = '8' 
mov ah, 02h
int 21h          ; outputs '8'
```

**BUT** all of the above will work *if and only if* you input 2 single digit numbers whose sum is actually less than 10. If it isn't you'll need to output more than 1 character in order to show the result from the addition.

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53158760/how-to-print-an-integer-stored-in-a-variable/53207238#53207238) to see how you can deal with additions that go up to 99.

Comment: Thank you, All was just fine. My Error was entering the input in the console y make enter like in other consoles. Just my bad, Thank you!